# Build config to pass in to dbcontext as an argument so I can use it in a unit test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here is my db context class

```
  public class WorldContext : IdentityDbContext<WorldUser>
  {
    private IConfigurationRoot _config;
    public WorldContext(IConfigurationRoot config, DbContextOptions options): base(options)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
    public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stop> Stops { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:WorldContextConnection"]);
    }
  }
```

Here is the part of my test code where I'm trying to create an instance of my dbcontext.

```
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            var config = builder.Build();
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<WorldContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                .Options;
            var context = new WorldContext(config, options);
```

No errors in VS and builds fine, but the test fails with:

> Message: System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: connectionString

[There is reference to this in the stack trace:]

> at
>   TheWorld.DAL.Models.WorldContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder
>   optionsBuilder)

Comment: It says that the connection string is missing. Are you sure you have connection string set in config file wherer it needs to be ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I imagine this is passed in with the config parameter, which is what I'm struggling to build. Though because I'm using it for testing I'm using `.InMemoryDatabase` in the options so perhaps I shouldn't want to be using my actual connection string as I'm not trying to hit the actual database... (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create an instance of `DbContextOptions<WorldContext>` in your test class:

```
DbContextOptions<WorldContext> options;
var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<WorldContext>();
builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
options = builder.Options;
```

DbContextOptions instance will tell all the configurations for WorldContext, which database it will connect etc. Since it is a in-memory database, you don't need to send a connection string (IMHO). So there is no need for `IConfigurationRoot` parameter in your WoldContext contructor.

---

Then, create an instance of WorldContext class and use it:

```
var context = new WorldContext(options);
```

---

Or you are saying I don't want to change my constructor, this is necessary, then:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_config["ConnectionStrings:WorldContextConnection"]))
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This applies if the only argument WorldContext accepts is the option parameter. Im my case I need to pass in config AND options.
See start of my code:
`public WorldContext(IConfigurationRoot config, DbContextOptions options)`

Comment: - I can't just get rid of config in the worldcontext class or I'll break the rest of my project. I'm working with a sample project by Shaun Wildermuth from Pluralsight. It is unfortunate he gave no examples of unit testing with EF within the project.

Comment: Excellent! - The test passed but this broke my startup code, though all I needed to add was:         `else
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:WorldContextConnection"]);
        }`